# what is best frontend and backend tools to build management sites with the support of cross domain communication

Tags: content-management-system, crossdomain.xml

I am  building a web user manual  for a product . Use cases are

> The manual should only be accessible if the user is logged into a portal
> but the catch is the manual and the portal for authentication of user is located in different servers
> i also have doubt on how to scale the project for future cases

- what tech should i use in the front back and the middleware if any should be implemented

As of now i am trying php/mysql for backend . the cross domain part and front end i am clueless